# need help on htaccess, zend framework 2 project

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2

My Setup

**virtual host is** : http://loc1.localhost/

**virtual host configuration**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName loc1.localhost
   DocumentRoot E:\xampp\htdocs\loc1\public

   <Directory E:\xampp\htdocs\loc1\public>
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**my htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?loc1.localhost$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loc1/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /loc1/public/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?loc1.localhost$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /loc1/public/index.php [L]
```

I am able to see my site as loc1.localhost

the problem is I can't reference my css files under loc1/library

I believe there is something wrong with my htaccess

can anybody help me out?

Comment: Are you trying to access your CSS files from *below* the document root? Where exactly is your `.htaccess` file stored?

Comment: Everything should be relative to your `public` folder.

Comment: my htaccess is on E:\xampp\htdocs\loc1\

Comment: but this is working on a centos environment I'm just replicating the setup on my pc so I can do bugs

Answer (score 0):

Considering your document root is `E:\xampp\htdocs\loc1\public`, your index file, `.htaccess` file, and your assets (CSS and images, etc.) should be located there.

So:

```
loc1\public\
loc1\public\.htaccess
loc1\public\index.php
loc1\public\library\main.css
```

You cannot load any files from below the document root (that is, your `public` directory).

Comment: that's weird it's working on another server, a centos server that's why I'm confused right now, note that zend framework 2 modules are also outside public folder including their own module scope css and js

Comment: I'm not sure how it's done then - perhaps the Zend public folder isn't actually the document root? On the CentOS server, is the public folder inside the `public_html` folder?

Comment: yep, what I did was downloaded the same files from server updated virtual host and did the same htaccess